# Story About Contact with an Alien Race That Lives on a Different Time Scale

Tags: story-identification, aliens, first-contact

I remember a few months ago looking at a story about humans arriving on a planet and finding a microscopic alien race. This microscopic alien race lived on a different time scale where they aged a lot faster than the humans. A short time passes for the humans and by then, the aliens are technologically advanced enough to make contact but then decide not to give any information about technologies the humans haven't discovered yet. Hopefully anybody has an idea as to who the author is and what the title is?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have any recollection of the length of the story? Medium it was published in?

Comment: Hi, thanks! I'm pretty sure it was a sci-fi book that was less than 600 words. I think it was a stand-alone novel.

Comment: Are you sure the alien race was living on a **planet**? Your description sounds a lot like *Dragon's Egg* but that's about life on a neutron star, not a planet.

Comment: OH! Thank you so much! That's the book!

Comment: There was a sequel called *Starquake*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Possibly [Dragon's Egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Egg) by Robert Forward.

> In the story, Dragon's Egg is a neutron star with a surface gravity 67
>   billion times that of Earth, and inhabited by cheela, intelligent
>   creatures the size of a sesame seed who live, think and develop a
>   million times faster than humans. Most of the novel, from May to June
>   2050, chronicles the cheela civilization beginning with its discovery
>   of agriculture to advanced technology and its first face-to-face
>   contact with humans, who are observing the hyper-rapid evolution of
>   the cheela civilization from orbit around Dragon's Egg.

Note:  @user14111 mentioned this novel simultaneously in a comment...

Comment: Previously identified as the answer to [this other question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54769/does-anyone-remember-the-title-of-a-book-where-single-celled-organisms-save-some).

Comment: I had forgotten to have read that... :)