# Planet that goes through its entire history in a matter of Earth days

Tags: story-identification

Tripod-like creatures on a planet whose time is much more rapid than on the ship orbiting the planet.

The planet goes through its entire history in a matter of Earth days.

Comment: I’ve added the story identification tag because I assume that is what you are asking. If not feel free to [edit] this to clarify. Could you also add in some more information. What was this? When did you read/watch this?

Comment: This probably isn't what you're looking for, but Star Trek Voyager dealt with this exact scenario in one of its episodes. https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Blink_of_an_Eye_(episode)

Comment: Is it a novel, a story, a movie, a tv series?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tiny lifeforms on planetoid that live at accelerated time rate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84562/tiny-lifeforms-on-planetoid-that-live-at-accelerated-time-rate)

Comment: @Lexible not accepted so not a duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

Robert L. Forward's [Dragon's Egg](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6773)?

> Human scientists strive to establish a relationship with an
> intelligent alien race known as the Cheela, but their efforts are
> complicated by the fact that one Earth hour is equal to hundred of
> years on Dragon's Egg, the neutron star where the Cheela live.

The 'Cheela', if memory serves, are more slug-like than "tripod-like", though.

Comment: Are the cheela tripodical?

Comment: What does "tripod-like" mean?

Comment: I'm assuming three-legged.

Comment: "The Cheela are anatomically simple creatures, with an amorphous body from which they can extend and retract appendages and crystal bones at will. They regularly create tendrils and pseudopods for manipulating objects, and body pouches to carry them. The only permanent structures are their twelve, regularly-spaced red eyes, which can also be stretched in eyestalks for them to see beyond their extremely short body height."

Comment: When the cheela are badly injured they change to an inanimate tripod-like form for a time to recover.