# Story set on a planet/sun moving through our solar system with alien life experiencing many generations for a human generation

Tags: story-identification, science

I'm trying to find a story set on a planet/sun moving through our solar system with alien life experiencing many generations for a human generation. I recently found a reference to it online but I misplaced it.

I think it was set on a neutron star that was hurtling through our solar system. The races consists of very small individuals ( ~ nm ) and their life span is very rapid such that thousands of their generations pass for a humans.

Humans help them develop and they quickly surpass human development.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: The more information you can provide about the story (and when/where you read it), the more likely it is that someone can identify it for you. We recommend that you look at our Guide: [How to Ask a Good Story-ID Question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and see what info you can add to this question.

Comment: *Dragon's Egg* matches for the aliens experiencing much faster subjective time, but it's about humans visiting their nebula rather than them coming to us.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The neutron star is making a close pass to the Solar Systrm; that's why it's being explored.

Comment: Thank you, Spencer. I was unaware of that detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per my comment, and Spencer pointing out a relevant detail, this may be Robert L. Forward's *[Dragon's Egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Egg)*.

> In Dragon's Egg, Forward describes the history and development of a life form (the Cheela) that evolves on the surface of a neutron star (a highly dense collapsed star, about 20 km in diameter). This is the "dragon's egg" of the title, so named because from Earth it is observed to be near the tail of the constellation Draco ("the dragon"). The Cheela develop sentience and intelligence, despite their relative small size (an individual Cheela has approximately the volume of a sesame seed, but the mass of a human) and an intense gravity field that restricts their movement in the third dimension. Much of the book concerns the biologic and social development of the Cheela; a subplot is the arrival of a human vessel nearby the neutron star, and the eventual contact that is made between the humans and the Cheela. A major problem in this contact is that the Cheela live a million times more quickly than humans do; a Cheela year goes by in about 30 human seconds.
>
> The humans arrive when the Cheela are a savage, backward species, fighting rival clans in a subsistence-level society. Within a few human days, the equivalent of a few thousand Cheela years, the Cheela surpass the humans in technology, and the humans are affectionately called "the Slow Ones".

I have actually never read it myself, although I posted it as an answer at [Tiny lifeforms on planetoid that live at accelerated time rate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84562/tiny-lifeforms-on-planetoid-that-live-at-accelerated-time-rate), so I was unaware that the neutron star was moving close to Earth, allowing for the visit, but I do now see [at least one review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R17XBVN3JLXZS1/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B004G8PJDA) mentioning it:

> I like SciFi that has a firm foundation in real science, and Forward delivers this in spades with his book about life that evolves on the surface of a Neutron star. Humanity stumbles on the nearly invisible stellar remnant as it passes near earth, and we send an expedition to study the star before it flies past us.

Comment: It's definitely worth reading.

Comment: I've read that book, all the points match.