# Book about a small world which wants to communicate with a large one (humans?) on different time scales

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

I am looking for a book which tells the story of two worlds.

One of the worlds is very small and the other is very large (relatively to each other). The large one was I think populated with humans.

They try to communicate but the time scale in the two worlds is drastically different: a short time on the large one is orders of magnitude longer on the other one. This means that whatever is passed from one to the other will span generations.

The small world was dying I think.

There was a second book which describes the second phase of their interactions, after both sides understood the time rate difference and its implications.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds a lot like [Dragon's Egg](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004G8PJDA) and [Starquake](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345312333) by Robert L. Forward.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Egg)

> Dragon's Egg is a hard science fiction novel written by Robert L.
>   Forward and published in 1980. In the story, Dragon's Egg is a neutron
>   star with a surface gravity 67 billion times that of Earth, and
>   inhabited by cheela, intelligent creatures the size of a sesame seed
>   who live, think and develop a million times faster than humans. Most
>   of the novel, from May to June 2050, chronicles the cheela
>   civilization beginning with its discovery of agriculture to advanced
>   technology and its first face-to-face contact with humans, who are
>   observing the hyper-rapid evolution of the cheela civilization from
>   orbit around Dragon's Egg.

Comment: This is exactly the book I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Sounds like an interesting story.

Comment: Previously identified as the answer to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84562/tiny-lifeforms-on-planetoid-that-live-at-accelerated-time-rate/84565#84565) and [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81126/story-about-contact-with-an-alien-race-that-lives-on-a-different-time-scale); also [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54769/does-anyone-remember-the-title-of-a-book-where-single-celled-organisms-save-some) but the answer was not accepted.