# A short story (possibility written in the 80's), where humans visit an alien race that evolves fast?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, first-contact, evolution

I was from a wikipedia article. Humans discover a primitive race of aliens that are very small, whose sense of time is much more accelerated. Communication with the aliens can take hours for humans, but lifetimes for the aliens. The aliens see the humans as gods.

As the alien goes on with their progression in history, they reach a point where their technology is more advanced than humans.

I think the story is based on snapshot POV's of historical figures in the alien's history.

Comment: Was this set on the surface of a neutron star? I recall a story like that, but can't recall much else.

Comment: @MikeHarris Looks like DavidW found the one you're thinking of.

Comment: Worth noting that this is a very common theme in scifi. I *think* the first example is Microcosmic God from1941, but I wouldn't be surprised to hear that was based on something else. More recently, it was the basis for an episode of Love, Death and Robots, "Ice Age", which I would argue is the best of the series (by far IMHO).

Comment: @Maury Yep. "Microcosmic God" pops up in people's almost-consciousness and questions almost as often as "Nightfall" or "Harrison Bergeron". Except for "discovering" of someone's POV, the them matches.

Comment: [Star Trek](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Blink_of_an_Eye_(episode)) did it too 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Book about a small world which wants to communicate with a large one (humans?) on different time scales](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131190/book-about-a-small-world-which-wants-to-communicate-with-a-large-one-humans-o) (note: this is added automatically as part as a flag for duplicate)

Comment: @WoJ it’s not accepted/acknowledged as true, so it cannot be closed.

Comment: Doctor Who did this a couple years ago as well.  A spacecraft near a neutron star. Each minute at one end was a long time (days/ weeks?) at the other end.

Answer (score 36):

This is almost definitely [*Dragon's Egg*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Egg) by Robert L. Forward; the primitive (very briefly) race are the *cheela* and they live on the surface of a neutron star.

[image: Paperback cover of Dragon's Egg]

The cheela - who are described as the size of a sesame seed - live approximately a million times faster than humans, with a lifespan (for us) of about 40 minutes.  From the human point of view the story takes place over just a few weeks as the cheela advance from hunter-gatherers to a galactic-civilization and then, somehow, leave.  In exchange for the information that the human expedition transmitted that kick-started their civilization they leave a copy of everything they learned, but encoded so that humanity can only access bits of it at a time.

Comment: Forward also wrote a sequel to this called [_Starquake_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starquake_(novel)); the two together should really be considered a single story, as _Starquake_ picks up exactly where _Dragon's Egg_ left off, and continues the story of the _cheela_.

Comment: Don't know if this is the story OP was looking for, but it's definitely the one I remember!

Comment: And if so, a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84562/tiny-lifeforms-on-planetoid-that-live-at-accelerated-time-rate

Comment: This would've been my guess based on the details given by OP.

Comment: Except the OP asks about a short story, not a novel. Though it is possible he misremembers.

Comment: It may also be possible that the OP read an abridged version?

Comment: I was just thinking of this story earlier this week. You've saved me my own question! :)